# Rspec Stubbing Behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, functional-testing

I'm having some trouble with stubs, and I think I must be misunderstanding how they work.

Do stubs only exist within the context that they are created? That is my expectation, but in my experience if I stub a method within a context it still exists in another context.

my controller test is similar to this:

```
describe '.load_articles' do
  context 'articles' do
    before(:each) do
      Article.stub_chain(:meth1, :meth2).and_return(['article'])
    end
    it 'sets articles' do
      controller.load_articles.should == ['article']
    end

  end
  context 'no articles' do
    before(:each) do
      Article.stub_chain(:meth1, :meth2).and_return([])
    end
    it 'sets article' do
      controller.load_articles.should == []
    end

  end
end
```

and for the second example `controller.load_articles` still returns `['article']` when I'm expecting `[]`

I've been stuck on this for too long; any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is that the real file you're testing with, or did you pseudocode it?  The reason I ask is because you're not stubbing `load_articles` anywhere in the example, you're stubbing `meth1` and `meth2`.  The behavior you're seeing should not happen with proper stubbing within context blocks like that.

Comment: I'm now guessing `meth1` and `meth2` are just things that `load_articles` calls on `Article`, but there might be more under the covers that could help diagnose it.  Some specifics about the methods might be useful.  Also, is there any caching/memoization going on in there that might interfere?

Answer (score 1):

Stubs are cleared after each example. You can prove this pretty easily:

```
class Numero; end

describe Numero do
  context "Uno" do
    before do
      Numero.stub_chain(:meth1, :meth2) { 'uno' }
    end
    it "unos" do
      Numero.meth1.meth2.should == 'uno'
    end
  end
  context "Dos" do
    before do
      Numero.stub_chain(:meth1, :meth2) { 'dos' }
    end
    it "dosses" do
      Numero.meth1.meth2.should == 'dos'
    end
  end
end
```